# Zend plugin FlashMessenger is delayed one page refresh

Tags: php, zend-framework3, flashmessenger

I am using ZF3 and FlashMessenger plugin from zend. This plugin not required any configuration. I only override it with my custom class becouse I want to use two methods in other way:

```
class CustomFlashMessenger extends FlashMessenger
{
public function hasMessages($namespace = null)
{
    if (null !== $namespace) {
        return parent::hasMessages($namespace);
    }

    return parent::hasMessages('default') ||
        parent::hasMessages('error') ||
        parent::hasMessages('warning') ||
        parent::hasMessages('info') ||
        parent::hasMessages('success');
}

public function clearMessages($namespace = null)
{
    if (null !== $namespace) {
        return parent::clearMessages($namespace);
    }

    return parent::clearMessages('default') ||
        parent::clearMessages('error') ||
        parent::clearMessages('warning') ||
        parent::clearMessages('info') ||
        parent::clearMessages('success');
    }
}
```

It is registered in `Module.php` and it works fine.

My problem is, when I want to display messages to the screen:

UserController.php

```
    public function loginAction()
{
    $form = new LoginForm();

    if (null !== $this->identity()) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');
    }

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $data = $this->params()->fromPost();
        $form->setData($data);

        if (!$form->isValid()) {
            foreach ($form->getMessages() as $message) {
                if (is_array($message)) {
                    $message = array_pop($message);
                }
                $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage($message);
            }
        }

        $data = $form->getData();
        $result = $this->authManager->login($data[ 'login' ], $data[ 'password' ], $data[ 'remember_me' ]);

        if ($result->getCode() == Result::SUCCESS) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');
        } else {
            $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('Error');
        }
    }

    $this->layout()->setTemplate('layout/login');

    return new ViewModel(
        [
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
}
```

layout/login.phtml

```
<?php if ($this->flashMessenger()->hasMessages()) { ?>
        <div class="message">
            <?php echo $this->partial('partial/messages'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

partial/messages.phtml

```
<?php
echo $this->flashMessenger()->render('info');
echo $this->flashMessenger()->render('success');
echo $this->flashMessenger()->render('warning');
echo $this->flashMessenger()->render('error');
?>
```

My messages to view are delayed one page refresh.
Eg. scenario:

1. Going to login page
2. Want to login with bad password and clicking submit
3. Page refresh and can't find any information
4. Login with good creditentials and clicking submit
5. I am logged in and see error message (bad password) on home page.

Answer (score 1):

The flash messenger plugin is intended to displays message on the *next* request and is useful with e.g. the [post-request-get plugin](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc-plugin-prg).

If your code is generating messages in the same request that renders them, then simply pass the messages through to the view model directly, no plugin needed.

```
return new ViewModel(
    [
        'messages' => $form->getMessages(),
        // ... other variables
    ]
);
```

Not related to your question, but in the `loginAction` i nthe code you posted, the method `$this->authManager->login` is called regardless of whether your form has validated or not.  You may wish to put the call to that method in an else after the `if (!$form->isValid()) { ...`

Comment: I have already installed "zend-mvc-plugin-prg". About login action - I made it intentially to test flashMessenger. option with variable messages is not a proper way, because I'm using flashMessenger in many actions.. It should work globally...

My problem is flash messenger sending data not in 1 next request, but in second one for first time and then all messages are delayed for one request

Comment: Also flash-messenger has *current* methods. If you want to get messages which is generated current request, you can read that methods. Don't forget to `clearCurrentMesages` so they will not store to session. Checkout class: https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc-plugin-flashmessenger/blob/master/src/FlashMessenger.php#L417

Comment: @Mehmet SÖĞÜNMEZ Yes! Now its working fine! So could you tell me when I should use Messages (not CurrentMessages) ?

Comment: You shoul use `getMessages` method if request changed. If you check https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc-plugin-flashmessenger/blob/master/src/FlashMessenger.php#L636, it's reads messages just once. So messages you added on controller, will not be available on view with `getMessages` method.